# Pass a vector of unique_ptr to function, const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, stdvector

I usually pass a vector containing raw pointers like this:

```
someFunc(const std::vector<MyClass*>& classList){..}
```

I wonder if you can do the same with unique_ptr like this:

```
 someFunc(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>& classList){..}
```

? Does it mean the same thing?, i.e. read-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. No, it's doesn't mean the same thing: `std::unique_ptr` represents a resource that is owned by the pointer. A generic raw pointer can have many other semantics.

With regards to const correctness, accessing the elements of a vector with either iterators or `operator[]` will yield constant references to `std::unique_ptr`s. With a `const std::unique_ptr<T>` the pointer cannot be reassigned while the `T` object pointed to can be modified.

Comment: "the pointer cannot be reassigned while the T object pointed to can be modified.". So, it should be something like this: someFunc(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const MyClass>>& classList){..} ?

Comment: @karl88: Well, that would be like `std::vector<const MyClass*>`, which is not what the question does either.

Comment: @karl88 Well yes, you would need `std::unique_ptr<T const>` to prevent the object pointed to to be modified.